# AngularJs conversion of service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

the title to this is a bit ambiguous I know, but I couldn't think of what to call it :)

Hopefully this description will help.
I have this current "service" which looks like this:

```
.factory('MoltinApi', ['$cookies', '$q', '$resource', '$http', 'moltin_options', function ($cookies, $q, $resource, $http, options) {
    var api = $resource(options.url + options.version + '/:path', {
        path: '@path'
    });

    var authenticate = function () {
        if (!options.publicKey)
            return;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //var authData = angular.fromJson($cookies.authData);
        var authData = false;

        if (!authData) {
            console.log('from api');
            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: options.url + 'oauth/access_token',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: "grant_type=implicit&client_id=" + options.publicKey
            };

            deferred.resolve($http(request).success(function (response) {
                $cookies.authData = angular.toJson(response);
                setHeaders(response.access_token);
            }));
        } else {
            console.log('from cookie');
            deferred.resolve(setHeaders(authData.access_token));
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var setHeaders = function (token) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }

    return authenticate().then(function (response) {
        return api;
    });
}]);
```

As you can see, when we **authenticate**, we then return the **api** function.
I have decided that using **$resource** isn't working as good as I had hoped, so I have now tried to change the service to this:

```
.factory('MoltinApi', ['$cookies', '$q', '$http', 'moltin_options', function ($cookies, $q, $resource, $http, options) {
    // Private variables
    var headers;

    // Build request call
    var buildRequest = function (path, method, data) {
        var request = {
            method: method,
            url: options.url + options.version + path,
            data: data
        };

        console.log(headers);

        if (headers) {
            angular.extend(request, headers)
        }

        return $http.request(request);
    }

    // GET
    var $get = function (path) {
        var request = buildRequest(path, 'GET')

        return $http.request(request);
    }

    // POST
    var $post = function (path, data) {
        var request = buildRequest(path, 'POST', data)

        return $http.request(request);
    }

    // PUT
    var $update = function (path, data) {
        var request = buildRequest(path, 'PUT', data)

        return $http.request(request);
    }

    // DELETE
    var $delete = function (path) {
        var request = buildRequest(path, 'DELETE')

        return $http.request(request);
    }

    // authentication
    var authenticate = function () {
        if (!options.publicKey)
            return;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //var authData = angular.fromJson($cookies.authData);
        var authData = false;

        if (!authData) {
            console.log('from api');
            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: options.url + 'oauth/access_token',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: 'grant_type=implicit&client_id=' + options.publicKey
            };

            deferred.resolve($http(request).success(function (response) {
                $cookies.authData = angular.toJson(response);
                headers = { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.access_token } }
            }));
        } else {
            console.log('from cookie');
            deferred.resolve(
                headers = { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authData.access_token } }
            );
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return authenticate().then(function (response) {
        // Need to return $post, $get, $update and $delete
    });
}]);
```

But I am at a loss on how to return my methods **after** we have athenticated...
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap all the methods into an object, and return the object.  Try:

```
var api = {};
...
api.$get = function (path) {
...
api.$post = function (path, data) {
...
//etc

return authenticate().then(function (response) {
    return api;
});
```